# How to preselect one ng-repeat option based on the value from another ng repeat on view load?

Tags: angularjs, html

I have started to code in angular recently and i am building application that has front-end in HTML5 and Angular and i am stuck with one issue: I am trying to achieve that item  `{{city.name}}` is automatically selected from drop down menu based on it's `value="{{city.id}}` on view load

```
<div class="container1">
    <label class="lbl"><b>Select city</b></label>
    <select id="City" name="City" class="form-control" size="2" ng-model="selectedValue1">
        <option ng-repeat="city in chooseCities" value="{{city.id}} ">
            {{city.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

if `{{city.id}}` value matches with the item from second `ng-repeat` element `ng-model="con.id"`

```
<div ng-repeat="con in contact">
    <div ng-if="$index == 2">
        <div hidden>
            <input type="text" placeholder="City id" ng-model="con.id" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="lbl"><b>Zip code</b></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Street number" ng-model="con.zip_code" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which is representing the **city id** as well but is being pulled out from different (nested) **JSON array**:

```
2: {name: "Zagreb", zip_code: "10000", country_id: 1, id: 22}
3: {name: "Croatia", alpha_2: "HR", alpha_3: "HRV", id: 1}
4: {name: "MALE", id: 1}
```

via HTTP post request and the Angular controller looks like this.

```
$scope.editContact = function() {
        $scope.id = localStorage.getItem("id");
        localStorage.clear();
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/CrozApp/JSPContact',
            //url: 'http://10.0.2.2:8080/DocBackend/JSP',
            data: { action: $scope.action2, id: $scope.id },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            //console.log(data);

            if (data != null) {

                $scope.contact = data;

                console.log($scope.data);
            } else if (data == null) {
                alert("database empty or not accessible");
            }

        });
```

Basically the view is showing users data (**name, adresse, city name, country etc.**) and i would like to select town from the list of towns if it matches with the town that is binded to user. Both HTTP call methods are initialized by `ng-init` in view. I came across many similar problems on stack overflow and I assume some sort of filter or matching must be applied via controller or view but i am not able to figure out how. Working example would be fantastic to see.Thank you all in advance.

[Plunker version:](https://plnkr.co/edit/DpRp7Bkpqcm9nyCtOuVd?p=preview)

Comment: Can you set up an example in Plunker? Would be much easier to help.

Comment: Sure i ll set one

Comment: Hi  @tasseKATT ,here is the plunker version of that view: https://plnkr.co/edit/DpRp7Bkpqcm9nyCtOuVd?p=preview

Comment: Great, will take a look :)

Comment: The `contact` array seems weird. Why is it an array of four different looking objects? Will it always look like this? Need a way to know which object that contains the `city_id` property. If you select a city form the dropdown, should it update the input field?

Comment: @tasseKATT The array is looking like that because i am pulling data from multiple tables (5 tables) that are additional details to user so i want to fetch all data at one HTTP request and then manipulate with that data in the view if i want to update city name or country name etc.  When page loads i want that drop down select's a city name based on the city id from array contact. The dropdown will contain 20 citys for example and i want that drop down selects automatically  city London if user lives in London (if town id's match in two different arrays).

Comment: @tasseKATT If that can be achieved by comparing city's name's i don't have anything against it. The city id in contact array is object 2 (I have used ng-if on index 2 in view) and it will always look like that. Take your time and thank you for interest and help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the selected city to be preselected, but not the city id  of the contact to update when you choose one, you simply need manually to set the select's ng-model once at start when all the data is fetched.

Example:

```
function setSelectedCity() {

  var city = $scope.chooseCities.filter(function(city) {
    return city.id === $scope.contact[1].city_id;
  })[0];

  if (city) {
    $scope.selectedValue1 = city.id.toString();
  }
}

setSelectedCity();
```

Note that in this case the select's ng-model value will always be a string after choosing an option from the select.

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/rpvFZm1fx0e3u5nfUh6m?p=preview

If you want the city id of the contact to update as well, both the city id of the second object in the array and the entire third object should probably be updated since they are logically linked. This would require some more work and probably some changes to the data structure.

Comment: Let me know if you need help with the other scenario described at the bottom.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, exactly what i needed. Thank you man. I need to work out on my logic when solving this types of problem. The city id text field will be hidden by default so there will be no need to update one if we pick up another town from the list. I will only need to know the town id from drop box if updating and i believe i can handle that on my own. I just wanted to make that functionality to make life easier for someone who will update details. You have some skills :) Thank you

Comment: @BasicGuy Please don't forget to accept/upvote the answer :)

Comment: Both done :) Still my vote will not show up as i need to gain some rep. but i believe it is recorded correctly. All the best!